# Tagging People and Items in a Photo as an Overlay

Tags: social-media

Facebook or instagram (possibly flickr) use to have a highlight and tag type of functionality with uploaded images. I think it's an overlay type of thing but I cant figure out what its called or which company has it if any. It's been a while since I have been on social media.

So lets say I have a picture of a dog in a park, bridge in the background and a large body of water under the bridge. In the image upload screen after uploading i would select or highlight the dog and set the label to "Wolf - German Shepherd Age 5". I would then select the bridge the label is "Golden Gate Bridge San Francisco, Ca". I hit submit and it shows the pic on the pag. The dog would be highlighted in a color like red and the bridge would be highlighted in blue. When your mouse hovers over a highlighted item the appropriate label would appear.

See the attached to see a very crude and rough example of what I'm talking about. The idea is in image 1 when you hover over the red bird with purple highlighting you get what you see in image 2 with the tool tip Identifying its a red bird.

Image 1

https://ibb.co/YbGWz7z

Image 2

https://ibb.co/3RH6f9K

Anyone remember the social media company that use to have this (or maybe still does) or know what this effect is called.